# ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK with Cocoapods 0.39

Tags: ios, cocoapods, skmaps

I updated Cocoapods to 0.39 today, it seems that this version introduces some issues with Scout Maps dependencies as I get the following error for what was a previously functional podfile.

The podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'FMDB'
    pod 'Reachability'
    pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools'
    pod 'MRProgress'
    pod 'KTCenterFlowLayout'
end
```

And the error is this:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK` required by `Podfile`
- `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK (= 2.5)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK (~> 2.5.0)` required by `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools (2.5.0)`
```

I think ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK needs to be version 2.5.0 or you need to adjust the requirement in SDKTools to be ~> 2.5

Comment: Unfortunately on our side everything worked well. We've created a new project, added the exact same Podfile, with the same Cocoapods version and all pods were installed without any kind of error. 
Should point out the fact that the current version of SKMaps available through Cocoapods is 2.5.1, though we've tested the 2.5 one as well and everything went fine.

Comment: Can you add more information so that we can try to reproduce the problem?